# On the initial page load, Kendo UI Pager is not showing PageSizes drop-down

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a pager control that needs to show the pageSize drop-down. On the initial load of the page, the drop-down is not shown, but any resize events, even towards making the page narrower result in the drop-down to be shown.

Here is how the pager control is defined:

```
$("#pager").kendoPager({
        dataSource: vm.DataSource,
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100]
    }).data("kendoPager");
```

and here is how it looks when the page loads:

[image]

and here is how it looks if I resize the page in any way, even towards making the page *narrower*:

[image]

My question is why the Page Size drop-down is not visible when the page first loads?

Comment: Here's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64527934/3739517) that I've used in the past when this happens. As for why this happens? I'm not sure. Maybe the grid is just being initialized at a point where it thinks it's on mobile?

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Please feel free to post your reply as Answer, so I can accept it and you get some SO points.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can just give me an upvote on the answer I linked, since it's from me. :)

Answer (score 3):

you should resize the grid in the first load, so add this event handler to grid:

```
.Events(e => e.DataBound(@<text>
    function(e) 
    {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.pager.resize();            
    }
</text>))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide the nubmers and show the dropdown - example of [standalone Pager](https://dojo.telerik.com/EzEroFOy) or a [Grid](https://dojo.telerik.com/UmIMaYUP).

```
.k-pager-numbers{
      display:none;
    }
.k-pager-numbers-wrap select.k-dropdown, .k-pager-numbers-wrap select.k-dropdown-list, .k-pager-numbers-wrap select.k-dropdownlist{
      display:flex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was after an upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 2023.3.1117.95, some prior settings were interfering.

```
.Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100 }))
.DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().PageSize(10).Total(Model.Count).Events(e => e.Error("kendoReadError"))
.Read(read => read.Action("ReadSchedule", "Schedule")
.Data("GetScheduleData"))
.ServerOperation(false))
```

After I removed PageSize and Total, the page size drop down list, and item count label started to appear on render.

```
.Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100 }))
.DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Events(e => e.Error("kendoReadError"))
.Read(read => read.Action("ReadSchedule", "Schedule")
.Data("GetScheduleData"))
.ServerOperation(false))
```